# Javascripts seems to work intermittently for list collapsing and expanding in html

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I am using the code from - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDKLK/6/)

And I modified the code similar to -

```
<body>
  <ul>

    <li onclick="toggle('Items')"><b>Items</b></li>
    <ul id="Items" style="display:none">
      <!-- skeleton  start   -->
      <li onclick="toggle('Item1')"><b>Item1</b></li>
      <ul id="Item1" style="display:none">
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
        <li>Item4</li>
      </ul>
      <li onclick="toggle('Items5')"><b>Items5</b></li>
      <ul id="Items5" style="display:none">
        <li>Item6</li>
        <li>Item7</li>
      </ul>
      <li onclick="toggle('Items8')"><b>Items8</b></li>
      <ul id="Items8" style="display:none">
        <li onclick="toggle('Items9')"><b>Items9</b></li>
        <ul id="Items9" style="display:none">
          <li>Items10</li>
        </ul>
        <li onclick="toggle('Items11')"><b>Items11</b></li>
        <ul id="Items11" style="display:none">
          <li>Items12</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Items13/li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>

    <li onclick="toggle('newitems')"><b>Items-New</b></li>
      <ul id="newitems" style="display:none">
        <!-- skeleton  start   -->
        <li onclick="toggle('NewItem1')"><b>New Item1</b></li>
        <ul id="NewItem1" style="display:none">
          <li>NewItem2</li>
          <li>NewItem3</li>
          <li>NewItem4</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
  </ul>

</body>
```

But the problem is that at times it works and at times, it doesn't. I am able to expand collapse Items and sub items properly while sometimes it doesn't respond. I have no clue as why is it not working every time. At times, New Items doesn't expand and at times it does. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ajax? or adding items to your page with js?

Comment: Seems fine by me ... have you tried using other browser to see if it reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Morteza, no, I am not using ajax. Just the method in the jsfiddle and the content above.

Comment: @Rubenxfd, yeah, tried with different browsers but its same. The weird thing is that behavior is inconsistent and sporadic.

Comment: Can you add full page code? Seems fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mortezak1373/nu5u13rs/)

Comment: @Morteza, please visit [here](http://www.theaacharya.com/Trainings/) , click on `Java`, `Environment Setup` doesn't seem to work all the time. If you click on `Introduction to Java`, it starts working.

Comment: this element in your page cover your Environment Setup element
`<div class="vbox wb_container" id="wb_footer">
</div>`

Comment: @Morteza, awesome and absolutely right. Just wondering how did you figure that out? Thanks a bunch! How shall I mark this as an answer, don't see an option?

Comment: @Morteza, thank you so much. I understand it now. I just want to accept it as an answer, but unable to do it.

Comment: @AnujSingh please read this [How to accept answer and it's impact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

> please visit [here](http://www.theaacharya.com/Trainings/) , click on `Java`, `Environment Setup` doesn't seem to work all the time. If you click on `Introduction to Java`, it starts working.

this element in your page cover your Environment Setup element

`<div class="vbox wb_container" id="wb_footer"> </div>`